# HTML form is wrapping incorrectly, maybe something wrong with the floats?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this form:
[image: Desired form]

And this is what I get:
[image: Bad form]

(*I changed the button color, I know =)* )

Here is my HTML:

```
 <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Email" />
      <input type="submit" value="Keep me notified" id="submitButton"
 </form>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
form{
    width:350px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display:block;
}
input[type=text]{
      display:inline-block;
      font-family: 'PT Serif Caption', serif;
      border:1px solid #CCCBC2;
      display:inline;
      font-size:14px;
      width:300px;
      line-height: 16px;
      padding: 9px 10px;
      height: 18px; 
      margin:0;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      outline: 0;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 269px;
      float:left;

      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;  
      -webkit-border-radius:3px;
      -moz-border-radius:3px;
      -o-border-radius:3px;
      -ms-border-radius:3px;
      border-radius:3px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  display: inline-block;    
  background:none;
  padding:0 14px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 1px 0 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: visible;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2459a9;
  border:none;
  font-family: 'PT Serif Caption', serif;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -o-border-radius:3px;
  -ms-border-radius:3px;
   border-radius:3px;

}
```

My Q:

- How do I get the floats right? Or is it something else?
- Can you do it in html5? Cool, show me =)
- How do a implement a placeholder in the inputbox
- How do I get big letter in the button?

Comment: Don't you want to use tables? Always make things easy :P

Comment: No dude ^^ tabels are 1999 Lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. The form is too narrow for the total width of the inputs.  So for [the fiddle you provided](http://jsfiddle.net/mkZSz/1/), it should be 464px.
2. Use [`white-space: nowrap;`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) on the form.

[**See it at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkZSz/2/)

Comment: Aha cool =), do you know why I dont get all the margins and padding on  the other divs: jsfiddle.net/mkZSz/1

Comment: I fixt it. there where missing a extra s in "class" div.. Thank you brock

Comment: I dont think you need the white-space tag either.

Comment: If the container dimensions are not just right, you'll want that tag.  It also guards against breaking the layout from browser-to-browser or when the user changes the font size.

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VaZsc/)

Your form rule makes the form too small, causing the button to wrap on a new line.  Try this rule instead:

```
form {
    width: 440px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT:

This should work:

```
form {
    width: 440px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VaZsc/1/)

Comment: Joseph, yeah it work in the demo =) but not with the rest of my html/css files. Hmm there is something sneaky with my code.. should I publish it all?

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake that would help very much (preferably in the form of a demo site). :)

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mkZSz/1/ . You can grab the code and try it out in your computer =)

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake I'll look more later but width:700px will do it

Comment: on which div? =) I will also try to fix.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake aha. It's easier than that. just set the form to `display: inline` see my edit.